# How to integrate external user tables with WP?

Tags: login, user-roles, shared-user-tables

I have about 10K+ users that I get from a company feed (LDAP).  I can authenticate WP via SSO based on someone's username matching on the WP user table.  I would like to take the user table I have and combine it with the wp-user table so that I can set permissions, change display name and things like that.  Is there a best way to do this?

Also we have about 15 WP installs and will probably have 30 by mid next year.  How can I manage these users in one table given that some may have admin rights on one site yet not admin rights on another site?

Answer (score 1):

This seems pretty tricky and it depends very much on your needs. You could either alter the WP database on each install or make 1 3rd party database along with a script that registers them on the WP install and sets their permissions. The 2nd solutions seems better for me.

Create a database where you add each user with a row for each WP install where you specify their permissions.

Let's say you have the following permissions: subscriber, contributor, author, editor, admin. Make a database for each user and set their permission. Make a 3rd party script which registers them to the WP installs and sets their permissions. When you change a permission, query the WP installs and update it there.

You will need mostly the WP [Database description](https://codex.wordpress.org/Database_Description) and [wp_update_user](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_update_user) function.

Comment: In a perfect world I would want one table and a "role field" attributed to each WP install.  Seems like there would be others that would have ran across something like this before.